# Is it possible to configure bootable NVMe disk as read-only using Opal 2.0 spec?

Tags: linux, opal, sedutil, tcg-opal

According to [docs](https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil/wiki/Command-Syntax), one can set locking range to `ro` (see `setLockingRange <0-15> <ro|rw|lk> <password> <device>`).

That said, not sure what `setLockingRange` actually does and wasn’t able to find good documentation.

```
$ sedutil-cli --setLockingRange 0 RO passw0rd /dev/nvme0
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not? If you want to lock the entire drive, enable the global locking range and make it read-only:

```
sedutil-cli --enableLockingRange 0 passw0rd /dev/nvme0
sedutil-cli --setLockingRange 0 RO passw0rd /dev/nvme0
```

In case the drive is in initial state (brand new or reset), you will need to initialize SED features: set `Admin1`/`SID` passwords and activate `Admin` and `Locking` `SP`'s. With `sedutil` there is a convenience shortcut for these steps:

```
sedutil-cli --initialSetup passw0rd /dev/nvme0
```

[Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Self-encrypting_drives) might give you more insight on SEDs in general.

You can also lock the boot *partition* only. You will need to set up a separate locking range and put the partition on it.